# Mysql View uses Rank() function inside of case statement. Completely working query but causing errors on Reverse Engineer and error parsing DLL

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am on version 8.0.28 of MySQL, using MySQL Workbench, connected to AWS. I wrote a complex query, *that works well when run.* But when the query is put into a view, it gives an error that there was a parsing error. When I try using reverse engineer to possibly sync with my production database, the view returns **3 errors:**

> ERROR: (266, 971) "char" is not valid at this position, expecting a complete function call or other expression
>
> ERROR: (266, 980) Extraneous input ")" found, expecting ELSE, END, WHEN
> ERROR: (266, 982) "desc" is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

**I have run the query through several syntax checkers and it checks out.**
**Here is the query - Note that I have removed many cases, but it seems it has to do with the JSON_VALUE function, so reducing the query to just this case fails as well.**

```sql
Alter View `Place_View` AS
Select 
Event_Scores.*,
CASE
 WHEN Event_Scores.scored = 0
  THEN NULL
 WHEN Event_Scores.waitlist_type_id = 101 AND Event_Scores.round <> 4
  THEN RANK() OVER (
   PARTITION BY Event_Scores.event_id,Event_Scores.waitlist_type_id, Event_Scores.round
   ORDER BY Event_Scores.score DESC,Event_Scores.time ASC,JSON_VALUE(Event_Scores.additional_info,'$.objects_found') DESC
  ) 
 END AS place
from Event_Scores
join Events on Event_Scores.event_id = Events.event_id
join Event_Types ON Events.event_type_id = Event_Types.event_type_id
join Event_Dogs ON Event_Dogs.`event_id` = `Event_Scores`.`event_id`
 AND `Event_Dogs`.`dog_id` = `Event_Scores`.`dog_id`
 AND `Event_Dogs`.`waitlist_type_id` = `Event_Scores`.`waitlist_type_id`
 AND CASE
  WHEN `Event_Dogs`.`round` = 0 THEN 1
  WHEN `Event_Dogs`.`round` = `Event_Scores`.`round` THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END = 1
```

I have tried using a subquery to access the JSON_VALUE() results. I tried to run Reverse Engineer Schema and also tried to view the View after creating it. Viewing it is fine but formatting is not supported for the Rank() function it seems. So the main problem is the Reverse Engineer function because I use this to sync my schemas between dev and production.

Comment: I don't see `char` anywhere in the code. Are you sure the error is from this?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, If I remove JSON_VALUE(), alter the View, and then reverse engineer again, the errors are removed.

Comment: But there's no `char` in the `JSON_VALUE()` call. The first error message says the problem is with `char`.

Comment: @Barmar True, but you can see that DESC is 2 characters after a ')' and that corresponds with the error message; so the char error is applying 10 characters earlier

Comment: None of these errors are mysql errors. Mysql syntax error messages have a different structure.

Comment: Maybe they're coming from Workbench? It might recognize the latest syntax.

Comment: Does it work if you use the `mysql` command-line client?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how to reverse engineer on the command line. The view works completely fine when I query it. The problem is just reverse engineering. So as Shadow said above, the error isn't coming from the engine.

Comment: There's nothing to reverse-engineer. Just paste the query at the `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: If you have a question regarding mysql workbench, then please ask it on mysql's support forum. That's not a programming or sw development related question we can help you with!

Comment: Without genuinely knowing anything "exact" about this at the level of complexity , two thoughts quite genuine with the error message (syntax)!   Put this on one line.   OVER (
   PARTITION BY Event_Scores.event_id,Event_Scores.waitlist_type_id, Event_Scores.round
   ORDER BY Event_Scores.score DESC,Event_Scores.time ASC,JSON_VALUE(Event_Scores.additional_info,'$.objects_found') DESC
  )       and try various ways of quoting or not quoting '$.objects_found'.      You took your query from one interpreter execution environment and put it into as different interpreter environment.

Comment: Running select * from Place_View works yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem. I contacted MySQL and they confirmed that this is a bug. The software was adding "returning char 512" in the DLL when JSON_VALUE() is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).